# Qual è la differenza tra Scusa e Scusami?

Tags: word-usage, difference, english-comparison

The both carry the same meaning: "Excuse Me". But there has to be a difference in their usage.

Please answer in English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no difference, you can just choose the one that sounds better. "Scusami" literally means "excuse me" and "scusa" means "excuse", but "me" is implied anyway (at least when "scusa" is used as an imperative verb; it can also be a noun, and that is a wholly different thing). Both can be used both as "sorry" and "excuse me". Both are informal.

Answer (score 0):

More or less the difference that there is between "sorry" an "excuse me".
The both convey the same meaning and they are informal in usage.

Comment: So how to express formal apology in Italian. What is the relevant  word or expression?

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsoodurRehman -                   It depends on what you mean by formal and if it is in spoken or  written form. "Porgo le mie scuse" is a written formal expression.

Comment: Some more intermediate expressions are "Mi scusi", "Chiedo scusa" and "Le chiedo scusa".

Answer (score -2):

Exactly the difference that there is between "excuse" and "excuse me". Very few!

Comment: Welcome! I'm not sure “excuse” alone is grammatical in English. “Very few” should be “very small”. Besides, this is already covered in other answers.